# Getting from id column name to class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Given a column name in string format (e.g. "hamburger_id" or "foo_bar_id"), is there a standard way of getting to a class (or class name). In this case, Hamburger or FooBar?

The only way I could think of was this:

```
column_name[0, column_name.length - 3].camelize.constantize
```

I can assume (or stipulate) that the variable column_name always contains a string with "_id" at the end and that a corresponding class always exists.

If some one finds it relevant or is curious, I can elaborate on the "why", but I didn't want to clutter up the question with such details.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following (assuming the traditional Rails example of a Post model that has_many Comment models):

```
Model.reflect_on_all_associations.select{|a| a.foreign_key == 'column_name'}.first.class_name
```

This has the advantage that if your class names and foreign keys don't line up, it will still give the correct class name. For instance, if your foreign key is `owner_id` but the associated model is actually named `User`, this will return `"User"` instead of `"Owner"`.

This still feels like a bit of a hack, but that's because it's not very Rails-like to get this information based on a column name - Normally you'd interact with the association directly (using `reflect_on_association(:foos)`).

Comment: Thanks! Good call on the non-conventional model names.

Comment: Is this Rails 3.1 specific? I looked at the Association objects returned using this call in 3.0.7 and they don't have a "foreign_key" attribute :\

Comment: I'm actually using 3.2.11 at the moment - I don't see anything about this being a recent addition to AssociationReflection, but I can't rule it out.